# how to structure a mysql subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a users table, and an appointments table.  For any given day, I would like a query that selects

1) the user_id the appointment is scheduled with

2) the number of appointments for that user for the specified day.

It seems I can one or the other, but I'm unsure of how to do it with one query.  For instance, I can do:

```
SELECT user_id FROM appt_tbl WHERE DATE(appt_date_time) = '2012-10-14' 
group by user_id;
```

Which will give me the users that have an appointment that day, but how can I add to this query another column that will give me how many appointments each user has?  Assuming I need some kind of subquery, but I'm unsure of how to structure that.

Comment: This is not related to subquery. Its group-by question

Comment: Thanks shiplu.modadd.im, I just realized that after seeing the other answers.  Thank you!  using count(*) is working as expected!

Comment: If you got an answer dot forget to mark it. :)

Comment: I just did, the site throttles how fast I can accept an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL uses the notion of "aggregate functions" to get you this information. You can use them with any aggregating query (i.e. it has "group by" in it).

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) as num_apts ...
```

Comment: Ah, count is what I was missing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding COUNT(*) to your query:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) FROM appt_tbl WHERE DATE(appt_date_time) = '2012-10-14' 
group by user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks Brendan, count is indeed what I was missing.  Thanks for the quick reply!